# What does ##__VA_ARGS__ mean?

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor, variadic-macros

I would like to know what `##` does in this macro definition:

```
#define debug(M, ...) fprintf(stderr,M "\n",##__VA_ARGS __)
```

I googled for an answer and I came up with the following.

The `##` will remove the comma if no variable arguments are given to the macro.  So, if the macro is invoked like this

```
debug("message");
```

with no quotes, it is expanded to

```
fprintf(stderr,"message");
```

not

```
fprintf(stderr,"message",);
```

Why is the comma removed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a non-portable syntax introduced by gcc to specifically deal with this corner case of passing no arguments at all.
Without the ## it would complain about the trailing comma being a syntax error.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html

C++20 introduced `__VA_OPT__` for this purpose:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the general behavior of ## ,concatenation, right?

Comment: Yeah it's just abusing that operator.

Comment: As of C++20 you will be able to do this in a standardized way:
`#define debug(M, ...) fprintf(stderr,M "\n" __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS __)`

Comment: @CarloWood It seems that VS2017 does not support __VA_OPT__(,)

Comment: @Maverick didn't he just say "As of C++20"? :)

Comment: @JohannGerell Yes, I wanted just to make it clear and bold, that even a pro version of the Visual Studio version 2017 that I own, does not support this macro that I arbitrarily thought in the begging......

Comment: For C++20 support you'll almost certainly need 2019.

Comment: VS2017 won't support C++20 lol. Hopefully VS2020 will, if you're lucky :p. For the documentation see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

Answer (score 2):

from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

```
Note: some compilers offer an extension that allows ## to appear after a
comma and before __VA_ARGS__, in which case the ## does nothing when the 
variable arguments are present, but removes the comma when the variable
arguments are not present: this makes it possible to define macros such as
fprintf (stderr, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```