# portability and safety of C macro using lambda parameter

Tags: c, lambda, macros

### Preface

I know that there are several libraries for auto-testing available.
Let's ignore that for this question, please.

### Motivation

Implementing some library I got tired of manual testing, so I started to write a "self-test" program, starting with code using many `assert()`s.
Unfortunately when an `assert()` fails, only limited information is shown on the screen, and I would typically have to use the debugger to examine the core dump to get more *details of the failure*.

So I added a macro that allows a `printf()`-like output (implemented via the `E()` (for *error*) macro) when an assertion fails; I named that macro `VA()` (for *verbose assertion*):

```c
#define VA(assert_cond, msg, ...)   do { \
    if ( !(assert_cond) ) E(msg, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    assert(assert_cond); \
} while (0)
```

Using that would look like this:

```c
    VA(FASTWORD(FASTWORD_BITS - 1) == 0, "%s: FASTWORD() failed", __func__);
```

As the self-test program used array-like data structures, I needed to inspact those as well, so I output those before doing the tests, resulting in a lot of output even when all tests succeed.

So I invented another macro, `VFA()` (*verbose failed assertion*) that uses a "*lambda parameter*" like this:

```c
#define VFA(assert_cond, cmd, msg, ...) do {    \
    if ( !(assert_cond) ) { \
        E(msg, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        cmd; \
    } \
    assert(assert_cond); \
} while (0)
```

While writing that I wondered how the preprocessor would parse commata for a use case like this:

```c
    VFA(fw[0] == out_fw0 && fw[1] == out_fw1,
        dump_fastwords_range(fw, 4, pos, (pos + count) % FASTWORD_BITS),
        "%s: __clear_fw_bits_up(%d, %d) failed", context, pos, count);
```

I mean it could be possible that the condition could be the first parameter, `dump_fastwords_range(fw` could be the second, `4` could be the third, and so on...

However that is not the case with `gcc` at least.

The other thing is `cmd;` in the macro:
My first version did not include the semicolon, so I would have to write (which looks really ugly):

```c
    VFA(fw[0] == out_fw0 && fw[1] == out_fw1,
        dump_fastwords_range(fw, 4, pos, (pos + count) % FASTWORD_BITS);,
        "%s: __clear_fw_bits_up(%d, %d) failed", context, pos, count);
```

OK, here's another use example of my macro:

```c
    VFA(fw[0] == out_fw0 && fw[1] == out_fw1,
    {
        const unsigned first = pos >= count ?
            pos - count : FASTWORD_BITS + pos - count + 1;

        dump_fastwords_range(fw, 4, first, pos);
    },
        "%s: __clear_fw_bits_dn(%d, %d) failed", context, pos, count);
```

### Questions

The questions I have are:

1. Is parsing of the macro parameters portable across compilers?
2. Will the `cmd` use create any trouble, considering the parameter could be rather complex (as the last example suggests)?

Comment: C allows quite long identifiers. Instead of naming stuff utterly cryptical like `VA` and then come up with an explanation what it stands for, just name the macro `verbose_assert`. Similarly, don't name something "`E` for error", name it `print_err` or something. There are few things that are more annoying to other C programmers than forcing them to learn a secret macro language in order to read your code.

Comment: A common, well-known trick is to write asserts like `assert(("Failed to do stuff",cond));` where the `,` is the comma operator. Most compilers will then give an error like: "Assertion failed at line x, Expression: ("Failed to do stuff",0)". That's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @Lundin In general I agree with your statement about short and cryptic names, but the self-test module isn't intended for end-users to see. And when entering hundreds of tests, I typically tend to mistype those lengthy names.

Comment: "I don't like/manage typing" is not a valid rationale to use when designing programs. Any decent IDE out there has a code completion feature. And there's always copy/paste. Apart from that, the programmer profession is all about typing a whole lot. Those who don't like it are probably better off pursuing some other career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is parsing of the macro parameters portable across compilers?

No. `##__VA_ARGS__` is a non-portable gcc extension. [What does ##__VA_ARGS__ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891546/what-does-va-args-mean)

> Will the cmd use create any trouble, considering the parameter could be rather complex (as the last example suggests)?

Items within `()` of that macro parameter will mean that it all gets treated like a single pre-processor token and expanded as such. You can peek at the pre-processor output if you are curious. Formally this is specified in C17 6.10.3/10:

> Each subsequent instance of the
> function-like macro name followed by a `(` as the next preprocessing token introduces the
> sequence of preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the definition
> (an invocation of the macro). The replaced sequence of preprocessing tokens is
> terminated by the matching `)` preprocessing token, skipping intervening matched pairs of left and right parenthesis preprocessing tokens.

So it shouldn't create any trouble unless you do truly evil stuff like using `goto` or `setjmp` etc from inside it.

Comment: Can you cite a reference where the "balpar feature" (handling items within a balanced pair of parentheses as one parameter) is explained. I failed to find it when searching yesterday.

Comment: @U.Windl Reference added to the answer.

Comment: I could not find a public document, but I found "*The individual arguments within the list are separated by comma preprocessing tokens, but comma preprocessing tokens between matching inner parentheses do not separate arguments.*" in "*19.3  Macro replacement*" on page 439 in [Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)

Comment: @U.Windl That's the wrong language, but you'll find the same text in the C standard if you read the next paragraph after the one I quoted, C17 6.10.3/11.

Comment: I'm aware that the doc cited from was C++, not C. However finding a C++ document is better than finding nothing at all. After all I don't think there are significant differences between the C and C++ preprocessor.

Comment: @U.Windl C++ didn't have variadic macros until C++11. C had it since C99. And I think C++ added some feature similar to the `##__VA_ARGS__` extension, to solve the problem that all arguments must be used. C doesn't have that.